# Ubuntu 10.10 "-unix is deprecated"

Tags: ubuntu, qt, meego

HI

I'm trying to install the MeeGo development SDK and when I run the command:

`# mad  -t meego-core-armv7l-1.1 qmake`

it gives me the error that `-unix is deprecated`.

I know absolutely nothing about unix/linux and I'm just following the instructions from here: http://wiki.meego.com/SDK/Docs/1.1/Getting_started_with_the_MeeGo_SDK_for_Linux

Does anyone know what to do?

Thanks

Tom

Comment: Are you sure "is deprecated" is an error and not just a warning?

Comment: hmm, maybe. i am a complete linux newbie and have no idea. i don't know how to check if thats the error or if its something else.

Comment: Probably just a warning, referring to something called a "UNIX Domain Socket" - it's like a TCP/IP connection but it doesn't go through the networking stack, it's local only.

Answer (score 1):

This is a qmake problem. basically what happened is that you passed a -unix flag into qmake.

This is not an error & just a warning. You can consider editing the file `/usr/lib/madde/linux-i686/madlib/mad-exec-env.sh` to remove the -unix flag.

But as the usual saying go, if it ain't broken, don't fix it.